# Jaeger Kubernetes Operator Setup

Tags: open-telemetry, jaeger, kubernetes-operator

I'm trying to setup Jaeger Kubernetes Operator to deploy jaeger all-in-one 1.50 solution in testing environment. As stated in [Jaeger documentation](https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.50/operator/), I have to create a namespace and then launch the following command:

```
kubectl create -f https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-operator/releases/download/v1.50.0/jaeger-operator.yaml -n observability
```

The link above is broken, any idea where I can find it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the following [github page](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-operator/blob/main/config/manager/manager.yaml) exposing jaeger-operator yaml definition. Otherwise, there are several helm package to run all-in-one jaeger solution.

Answer (score 0):

The 1.50 operator is not released yet, this is an ongoing issue with the coupling we have. The next release due in a couple of weeks (Dec 2023), v1.51 should resolve the problem for good.

https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-operator/issues/2349